# Trying to create a CSR with openssl, but openssl doesn't know what -config is

Tags: openssl

Following [this guide](https://www.switch.ch/pki/manage/request/csr-openssl/), I am trying to generate a csr file:

```
$ touch myserver.key
$ chmod 600 myserver.key
$ openssl req -new -config myserver.cnf -keyout myserver.key -out myserver.csr
```

but it gives:

```
unknown option -config server.example.com.cnf
```

But help also quotes -new and -config as valid parameters.

```
 -config file   request template file.
 -new           new request.
```

Comment: Did you copy/paste from a website? Sometimes an em dash (long hyphen) is used, which command don't understand.

Comment: Copying the command from your question works for me. What’s the output of `openssl version` for you?

Comment: This worked for me as well, but only after I created myserver.cnf as per the guide.   "openssl version" is OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31 Mar 2020 on my Ubuntu 20.04 install.